# PHP json_encoded object not passing to other page

Tags: php, object, json

I'm using `json_encode` on an object and stored on a hidden text field, When i was passing to the next page i didn't get any data

Code:

`$flight = json_encode($od->FlightSegments);`

Response page:

`<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` printed `Array ( [flight] => { )`

`serialize` and `unserialize` not working on my object.
Can any one tell me what's going wrong ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($od->FlightSegments);` give ?

Comment: $od->FlightSegments contains xml objects

Comment: If you're printing it in a web page, the XML is being rendered by the browser as HTML.

Comment: $xml = simplexml_load_string($result); used this, Given me the XMLObjects, Its successfully rendered by the browser

Answer (score 0):

To see XML literally on the web page, use:

```
<?php echo '<pre>' . htmlentities(print_r($_POST, true)) . '</pre>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `serialize` and `unserialize` are not giving me the correct output for me, I solved my problem using below code.

```
$count = 0;
$_SESSION['fl'] = [];
foreach($response->Response__Depart->OriginDestinationOptions->OriginDestinationOption as $od){
     $flight = json_encode($od->FlightSegments);
     $_SESSION['fl'][$count] = $flight;
}
```

Stored entire object into a session array